# Is it possible to merge all these three functions in only one by adding a new parameter and without using eval?

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters

That is a simple question about JS parameters and methods.
Is it possible to merge all these three functions in only one adding a new parameter without eval?

```
var content_big = function(id){
    var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.big();
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
};

var content_small = function(id){
    var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.small();
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
};

var content_fontsize = function(id, size){
    var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.fontsize(size);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;

};
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JuantxoCruz/wcbpqnb4/)

Comment: What do you think you're doing with `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.fontsize(size);` because `.innerHTML` retrieves a string which does not have a `.fontsize()` method?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontsize. In the jsfiddle is working.

Comment: I know the methods are deprecated, the question is about if it´s possible to merge the functions in only one. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but knowing what practical thing you're actually trying to do allows us to provide more appropriate and useful answers.  I try to provide answers that work, not theoretical answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't quite follow your uses of `.small()` and `.big()`, here's a generic way to do it with one function.  You pass in the method name and argument you want to pass it and the function uses the `[xxx]` syntax to call a method from a string (without using `eval()`) like this:

```
function changeContent(id, method, arg) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML[method](arg);
}

changeContent("test", "big");
changeContent("headline", "fontsize", 14);
```

Comment: Yes, it´s true, I didn´t remember the square braket notation. Thanks jfriend00!!

Comment: @JuantxoCruz - since it looks like you're relatively new here on StackOverflow so you know that you can accept an answer that solves your problem by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That earns both you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points.

Comment: Uhh! Thanks jfriend00!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Christos gave me an idea:

```
var content = function(id, secondParameter){
    var element = document.getElementById(id),
    html,
    numberParameter = secondParameter;

    if (!!secondParameter && ( secondParameter === ("big" || "small") ) ||  ( typeof secondParameter === 'number' )){
        switch(secondParameter){
            case "big":
                html = element.innerHTML.big();
                break;
            case "small":
                html = element.innerHTML.small();
                break;
            default:
                numberParameter = Math.round(secondParameter);
                html = element.innerHTML.fontsize(numberParameter);
        }
        element.innerHTML = html;

    } else return;

};

content('big', 'big');
content('small', 'small');
content('fontsize', 30.4);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuantxoCruz/g8s0c8vv/).

I think should be other approachs. Thanks.